# COPY local commits to another branch

Tags: git, rebase

I am reading rebase documentation. Rebase "Forward-port local commits to the updated upstream head". Ok, ... is possible to `copy` local commits to the update upstream?

This is the starting point:

```
           o---o---o---o---o  master
                \
                 o---o---o---o---o  next
                                  \
                                   o---o---o  topic
```

This is what I can obtain with rebase:

```
           o---o---o---o---o  master
               |            \
               |             o'--o'--o'  topic
                \
                 o---o---o---o---o  next
```

This is what I want:

```
           o---o---o---o---o  master
               |            \
               |             o'--o'--o'  new topic
                \
                 o---o---o---o---o  next
                                  \
                                   o---o---o  topic
```

There is not a reason: I am just asking if it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `git checkout -b topic2 master`

   ```
   o---o---o---o---o  master / topic2
               \
                o---o---o---o---o  next
                                 \
                                  o---o---o  topic
   ```
2. `git rebase --onto topic2 next topic`

   Rebase all commits from `next` (exclusive) to topic (inclusive) onto `topic2`

   ```
    o---o---o---o---o  master
          |            \
          |             o'--o'--o'  topic2
           \
            o---o---o---o---o  next
                             \
                              o---o---o  topic
   ```

**PS:** If you already rebased the `topic` branch

```
       o---o---o---o---o  master
           |            \
           |             o'--o'--o'  topic
            \
             o---o---o---o---o  next
```

the 'old' commits are not gone. Check the `git reflog` and you can re-create the 'old' branch.

```
 git checkout -b old_topic <TOPIC_COMMIT_ID_BEFORE_REBASE>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply make a new branch and rebase that one.

```
git checkout topic
git checkout -b new_topic
git rebase next new_topic --onto master
```

Comment: Thank you, I accepted another answer just because more complete. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from `rebase` which is a, let's say, more complex, tool, there is also a `cherry-pick` command that directly performs a copy of a commit.

Start with creating a new branch at master and checkout to it. Now note/read/view the **hashes** of all commits you want to copy:

```
           o---o---o---o---o  master / new-topic
               |           
               |           
                \
                 o---o---o---o---o  next
                                  \
                                   C---B---A  topic
                                   :   :   :
                                   :   :   ^ commit hash AAAAA
                                   :   ^ commit hash BBBBB
                                   ^ commit hash CCCCC
```

Sitting at `new-topic` branch, issue:

```
git cherry-pick CCCCC

           o---o---o---o---o  master
               |            \
               |             c'  new-topic
                \
                 o---o---o---o---o  next
                                  \
                                   C---B---A  topic

git cherry-pick BBBBB
git cherry-pick AAAAA

           o---o---o---o---o  master
               |            \
               |             c'---b'---a'  new-topic
                \
                 o---o---o---o---o  next
                                  \
                                   C---B---A  topic
```

You can switch their order, use `--no-commit` and patch them in the meantime, etc - just like during when `rebase --interactive`, but step by step and manually. Actually, you may consider `rebase` to be something like nice mass automated `cherry-pick`.

Comment: Thank you, but the question does not ask to move commits one by one.